# kotlin: extracting from list

Tags: list, kotlin, methods

I have a list of Int items say 
Now I want to call a function process(item1, item2, item3, item4)

How can I do this in kotlin.
I want to pass how much ever items are present in the list to the method. The method accepts variable number of arguments

I want to call this method from firbase mlk library

```
public FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetectorOptions.Builder 

    setBarcodeFormats(@BarcodeFormat int var1, @BarcodeFormat int... var2) {
    }
```

So I need to call setBarcodeFormats(is there a way in kotlin to pass each element of list as an arg here)

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Make the function accept an iterator and use `forEach`. Also [check](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/for-each.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the description of your problem I assume you have one method that takes a variable number of integers – let's call it `fun foo(vararg n: Int)`.

If that's the case, than the bytecode that gets generated is the following:

```
public final static varargs foo([I)V
```

This means the method takes an array of `int`, which is an `IntArray` in Kotlin world.

In order to call that method with an `IntArray` you need to do:

```
fun foo(vararg n: Int) {
    n.forEach(::println) // do something with n
}

fun main() {
    val numbers = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
    foo(*numbers) // prints 1; 2; 3; 4
}
```

In that snippet of code, `*` is the **spread operator** and is briefly described [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs).

Also note that the spread operator can only be applied to arrays, so if you have a list of `Int` you need to convert it to an `IntArray` first an then apply the spread operator, like this:

```
fun foo(vararg n: Int) {
    n.forEach(::println) // do something with n
}

fun main() {
    val numbers = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
    foo(*numbers.toIntArray()) // prints 1; 2; 3; 4
}
```

---

### EDIT

Following the update to your question, you can call that method from your Kotlin code like this:

```
val builder = ... // obtain a Builder instance
val args = intArrayOf(1, 2, 4, 10)
builder.setBarcodeFormats(1, *args) // or any other meaningful value
```

Comment: I have added exactly what I want to call. Its not accepting toIntArray / asList

Comment: @png please see the update to my answer. I believe your attempt doesn't work because the 1st argument of the method comes "outside" the varags, so you need to explicitly provide it

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways. First is pass a `List` of `Int` to the method. second is using `varargs`. For example a function which takes n number as inputs and returns the average of all the inputs. If we want to use List it will be like so:

```
fun getAverage(numbersList: List<Int>): Float {

    var sum = 0.0f
    for (item in numbersList) {
        sum += item
    }
    return (sum / numbersList.size)
}
val arrayList = arrayListOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
val result = getAverage(arrayList)
```

And if we want to pass numbers as infinite function parameters we could do it with `varargs` like this:

```
fun getAverage(vararg input: Int): Float {
    var sum = 0.0f
    for (item in input) {
        sum += item
    }
    return (sum / input.size)
}
val result1 = getAverage(1, 2, 3)
val result2 = getAverage(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The method I called is from a library. So i dont have control over that. It doesnt accept passing list